# Keeping only the duplicates

Tags: sas

I'm trying to keep only the duplicate results for one column in a table. This is what I have.

```
proc sql; 
    create table DUPLICATES as 
    select Address, count(*) as count 
    from TEST_TABLE
    group by Address
    having COUNT gt 1 
    ;
quit;
```

Is there any easier way to do this or an alternative I didn't think of? It seems goofy that I then have to re-join it with the original table to get my answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's easy using a data step:

```
proc sort data=TEST_TABLE nodupkey dupout=dups; 
 by Address; 
run;
```

Refer to this [documentation](http://www.nesug.org/proceedings/nesug06/cc/cc24.pdf) for further information

Answer (score 8):

```
proc sort data=TEST_TABLE;
    by Address;
run;

data DUPLICATES;
    set TEST_TABLE;
    by Address;
    if not (first.Address and last.Address) then output;
run;
```

Comment: Using proc sort with "dupout=" is a good way of de-duping your data, but it doesn't let you get a good view of all the duplicate records next to each other. In my experience duplicates are the result of something I did wrong in a prior step, so I want to see what I did wrong, not just fix it. Or, if actual data I want to see the similarities and differences of all duplicate-key records, so I can decide how to process (e.g. perhaps aggregate by the key).

Comment: Will your solution remove first and last row from output. i.e if i had 5 rows having same address it will only rows 2-4. I am confused about ```if not (first.Address and last.Address) then output;``` can you please elaborate what this line does?

Answer (score 8):

Using proc sort with nodupkey and dupout will dedupe the data and give you an "out" dataset with duplicate records from the original dataset, but the "out" dataset does not include EVERY record with the ID variable - it gives you the 2nd, 3rd, 4th...Nth. So you aren't comparing *all* the duplicate occurrences of the ID variable when you use this method. It's great when you know what you want to remove and define enough by variables to limit this precisely, or if you know that your records with duplicate IDs are identical in every way and you just want them removed.

When there are duplicates in a raw file I receive, I like to compare all records where ID has more than one occurrence.

```
proc sort data=test nouniquekeys
     uniqueout=singles
           out=dups;
by=ID;
run;
```

- **nouniquekeys** deletes unique observations from the "out" DS
- **uniqueout=dsname** stores unique observations
- **out=dsname** stores remaining observations

Again, this method is great for working with messy raw data, and for debugging if your code might have produced duplicates.

Answer (score 1):

```
select field,count(field) from table 
group by field having count(field) > 1
```

Comment: To help beginners, consider adding the proc prefix and suffix: proc sql; select field,count(field) from table 
group by field having count(field) > 1;